# VideoView not playing Video from desired position

Tags: android

i am using VideoView and seek bar but when i seekTo(..) on desired position through seekBar it play video from starting.

i trying this code:

```
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

           mVideoView.seekTo(progress);
}
```

Comment: @just i have doubt so i want to just know.Is VideoView working in emulator? or you are testing on device?Because i heard that VideoView is not working in emulator?

Comment: i am trying in both video view playing vedio but problem is seekTo() plz help

Comment: Could you post more code, so that we can understand the problem.

Answer (score 28):

As Reno mentioned, you have to wait for the seeking to complete.

`VideoView` does not have a `OnSeekCompleteListener()` but you can access the `MediaPlayer` from the `onPrepared` method of the `VideoView` and then set the `OnSeekCompleteListener`, like this :

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //TODO: Your code here
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I think this should be the preferred solution. it's much less dirty and much less troublesome than having to maintain your own fork of VideoView

Comment: Thank you! This is clearly the cleanest and most reliable solution. Everything else I've seen is a hacky mess.

Answer (score 6):

The call to `VideoView.seekTo()` is a wrapper around `MediaPlayer.seekTo()`. This function returns almost immediately even though the actual seeking is still being performed. Therefore you want to wait for seeking to complete via [`MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener.html).

However, as Reno mentioned, the standard `VideoView` does not support `OnSeekCompleteListener`.

**But you can copy and locally customize the `VideoView` class to add this support yourself.**

First, start with a copy of [VideoView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4b9a8d75b8796ea07cadd61ceef135c173167c8e/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java). Or you can clone the entire [frameworks/base](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/) repo but warning it is over 1 gig of data to download.

Copy VideoView.java into your Eclipse Android project and it will start building but fail. Here's what I did to get it to compile:

1. Update the *package* statement to match your project.
2. Comment out the references to `MetaData`. The fix for this is on my todo list. These need to be replaced with calls to [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).
3. Replace `mContext` with calls to `getBaseContext()`

Now you are ready to add the code for `OnSeekCompleteListener`. The implementation is similar to the other listeners, i.e `OnCompletionListener`.

```
public class VideoView extends SurfaceView
        implements MediaPlayerControl {

    // The client's listener which is the notification callback.
    private OnSeekCompleteListener mOnSeekCompleteListener;

    // Set up MediaPlayer to forward notifications to client.
    private MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener mSeekCompleteListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
            }
        }
    };

    // API for client to set their listener.
    public void setOnSeekCompleteListener(OnSeekCompleteListener l)
    {
        mOnSeekCompleteListener = l;
    }
}
```

Finally, update your own code:

1. Update references to `android.widget.VideoView` to use your customized `VideoView`.
2. Implement a listener and set it via by calling `setOnSeekCompleteListener()`.

Your code now receives notifications when the seek has really completed and it can then perform subsequent seeks.

Comment: It still doesnt work for me - i ve modified videoview but the listener still fires about 6 seconds before the actual time. Any idea why

Comment: Hi Slartibartfast, are you saying the listener is called 6 seconds before the seek is actually completed? I'm curious how you measured this.

Comment: Sorry, but what I need to do with MediaPlayer.METADATA_ALL,
MediaPlayer.BYPASS_METADATA_FILTER ,Metadata.PAUSE_AVAILABLE etc.? MediaPlayer and MediaMetadataRetriever doesn't have these constants.

Comment: Hi anivaler, I'm not familiar with these constants. But as you said, they are are not part of the MediaPlayer and MediaMetadataRetriever APIs so things should work with using them.

Answer (score 4):

You have to wait for the seeking to complete, unfortunately `VideoView` does not have a `OnSeekCompleteListener()` (why Google? -_-)

Comment: Sometimes Google'a api is really confusing, really bad coding experience

Answer (score 0):

use my method works like charm

1. Take mediaPlayer

   ```
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   ```
2. init mediaPlayer

   ```
   videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer = mp; 
        }
    });
   ```
3. use seekTo method like this

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) mStartPosition, MediaPlayer.SEEK_CLOSEST);
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) mStartPosition);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the listeners to start once seek is completed. The correct sequence to restart a video from a previously stored position using a `VideoView` would look like this in Kotlin.

### Video Position and Resume handling

Storing the position, could be done in `onPause` of Activity or any other lifecycle aware view:

```
val videoPosition = videoView.currentPosition
videoView.pause() // you can also use .stopPlayBack() since you'll restart anyway
```

And `onResume` you can resume playback from that stored position, note how listeners are used to detect video prepare and video seek being complete:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
   mediaPlayer.seekTo(videoPosition)
   mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener { seekMediaPlayer ->
      seekMediaPlayer.start()
}
```

### VideoView visibility

For all of this to work the actual `VideoView` has to be visible in the layout. If hidden (either using visibility `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`) the video will never prepare so nothing will happen.

If you encounter black screens or other artifacts caused by the view being visible before the content is fully loaded you can use `alpha` instead to hide it.

```
videoView.alpha = 0f
videoView.setOnInfoListener { _, what, _ ->
   if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START)
      videoView.alpha = 1f
   false
}
```

### Lifecycle handling

If you're working with an Activity or Fragment you can just hook onto the existing `onPause` and `onResume` methods.

```
override fun onPause() {
   // handlePauseVideo()
   super.onPause()
}

override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   // handleResumeVideo()
}
```

When working with a custom view you'll need to make it lifecycle aware like so:

```
init {
   inflate(context, R.layout.your_custom_view, this)
   (context as? LifecycleOwner)?.lifecycle?.addObserver(this)
}

override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
   // handlePauseVideo()
   super.onPause(owner)
}

override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
   super.onResume(owner)
   // handleResumeVideo()
}

override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
   // handleEndVideo()
   super.onDestroy(owner)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use

mVideoView.seekTo(progress, SEEK_CLOSEST)

Comment: That's not for VideoView.

Comment: VideoView Dont have Method named Seekto with two parameters. may be its a mediaplayer object