# android: seekcompleteListener to be used with VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, seek

Is there any way to use setOnSeekCompleteListener with VideoView. It is possible through MediaPlayer but I am using videoview in my application and need to use onSeekCompleteListener.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Farhan, I had the same problem and ended up copying and modifying the VideoView source, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11938019/783051

Answer (score 2):

`VideoView` does not have a `OnSeekCompleteListener()` but you can access the `MediaPlayer` from the `onPrepared` method of the `VideoView` and then set the `OnSeekCompleteListener`, like this :

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //TODO: Your code here
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get same functionality using the following method in VideoView

```
public void setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)
```

Comment: sir, Can you please elaborate a bit more towards it.