# the seekTo() function doesn't work in VideoView

Tags: android

There is a problem in my application,I want to use the `seekTo()` function with `VideoView` like this:

```
videoView.seekTo(time);
videoView.start();
```

It works well in `android 2.2` ,but doesn't work in `android 2.3` or higher version...
Some body will tell me why? It troubles me for serval days.

Comment: are you sure you're waiting for long enough to decide that it's not working? on one of my LG phones, for example, seekTo takes like forever. whereas on my other LG phone, it's actually not that bad

Comment: You can use MediaController Class in Android Which makes controlling of entire VideoView easy.

Answer (score 5):

The call to `VideoView.start()` should be made only after the seek has completed. The call to `VideoView.seekTo()` initiates a seek but unfortunately `VideoView` does not support `OnSeekCompleteListener` needed to notify the seek is actually done.

You can customize `VideoView` to support `OnSeekCompleteListener` as shown in [my answer to 7990784](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990784/videoview-not-playing-video-from-desired-position/11938019#11938019).

Then you can register to receive `onSeekComplete()` by calling `setOnSeekCompleteListener()`. Your implementation of the listener should then call `VideoView.start()`.

Comment: This is quite simply the best answer. Easy to implement and actually works. I get the reference to the `MediaPlayer` in `onPrepared()` and use it to do the rest (set `OnSeekListener` and call `seekTo()`).

Answer (score 1):

For proper operation of the method `seekTo()`,the video state should be in `PlaybackState`.

Checkout the `VideoView` [source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/VideoView.java#VideoView.isInPlaybackState%28%29) for get more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried VideoView class from **Vitamio** library?

[Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work. 
The problem may be that the mediaplayer inside `videoView` has not been created.

It's easy to test, by changing the orientation of the device. That's how I tested it.

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(onPreparedListener);
private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener onPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.seekTo(videoPosition);
    }
};
```