# VideoView seekto() function extremely inconsistent

Tags: android, android-videoview, seek

I am trying to Seek to a particular location in a video in Android and I am completely stuck because of the inconsistencies it is showing in its behaviour. Here's a list of things I ve done

> 1. VideoView.Seekto goes to 5:19 for one video, 5:17 for one video and 5:32 for another for the same milliseconds(326000 ms)!
> 2. Since VideoView does not support onSeekListener, I've modified the
>      source VideoView and added support for it. Yet it does not pause and
>      start seeking from where I want it to - there is always a lag! The
>      onSeekListener is called immediately some 6 s before where I want it
>      to stop. In many cases the seek bar shows the right time and suddenly jumps back a few seconds even though I am calling video.start
>      from onSeekCompleteListener

Why is this so inconsistent ? Is there a definite way of seeking to where you want to go in milliseconds in videoview? I know I should use MediaPLayer + Surface but since VideoView is just a wrapper of the two I am modifying it at source but to no avail.

I am aware of this : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9135 
But is there any way to get around this and have a definite way of

> 1.) Seeking to the exact time in milliseconds
>
> 2.) Pausing and resuming at the exact time?

Comment: im interested on this post. do you have an answer or explanation for this?

Comment: Basically this is the issue - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9135 let me know if you need specifics

Comment: The inaccuracy is in the media file itself, I believe. [This guy explains it well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6908256/931277).

Comment: I have the same problem! I can't start player from any position between 1st and 10th second! It starts playing either from the very beginning, or from the 10th second. Very weird. (Android 2.3.4, LG)

Comment: Hi @Slartibartfast got any solution...i have same problem please reply if you have got any sol on this. Thanks

Comment: @user3207655 if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11939135/1276636) works for you then please comment back. I guess it should do the trick. I might be adding it to my app too, regardless of your commenting back or not ;)

Comment: Hi @Sufian yes it has worked for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [the seekTo() function doesn't work in VideoView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328854/the-seekto-function-doesnt-work-in-videoview)

Comment: Well my question is more to do with the inconsistency of video view time seek, not with seek working/not working which the other answer seems to suggest. Although I don't remember what I did with this.I think we accepted the minor delta seek errors at that time. So to me I'm not sure if the other answers provide a way, that given a time X, seek to that point exactly

Comment: If you're willing to invest a bit of time, you can look into Exoplayer. It will give you much better seeking accuracy and control.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to wait for the seeking to complete.**

VideoView does not have a OnSeekCompleteListener() but you can access the MediaPlayer from the onPrepared method of the VideoView and then set the OnSeekCompleteListener, like this :

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Seek completed. Move seekbar
            } 
        }); 

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

10 years later and I came across the same question exactly.

Any way, for me, the solution was to use the mediaPlayer from inside VideoView (**Android Oreo 8.0+**):

[image]

Explanation:

**videoView** default seekTo function use mediaPlayer default seekTo function ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java#:%7E:text=public%20void%20seekTo(int%20msec)))

**mediaPlayer** default seekTo overload is the same as [seekTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#seekTo(long,%20int))(long, int) with SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC mode, you should use SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC only if you want to seek to a sync frame that has a timestamp earlier than or the same as milliseconds given,

However, SEEK_CLOSEST will seek to a frame that may or may not be a sync frame **but is closest to or the same as milliseconds.**

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not the proper solution to your question but take a look into this library that is being made over the Google's default video view

https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia

It has all the functionality and more that is being supported by default video view.

You can use this video view and `emVideoView.seekTo(1000);` to jump to 1000 millisecond in the video. You can also have `setOnSeekCompletionListener` to do process when seek complete.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18265533)

Comment: Sorry, Edited answer for better understanding rather then just pasting the URL.

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem like this

[the seekTo() function doesn't work in VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328854/the-seekto-function-doesnt-work-in-videoview/15720183#15720183)