# How to play a webm video at a seek position in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-seek

Here's my code where I play a video provided in link but on clicking at a particular time-point, it starts again to 0 position. I want to play the video from any selected position by user. I am using a webm video stored at the given link below. The video plays with play/pause funtionality however i cannot seek to a particular position in the video while streaming.

```
    String videolinkurl = "techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm";

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


    // Set the media controller buttons
    if (mediaController == null) {
        mediaController = new MediaController(sessionRecordingVideo.this);

        // Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController.
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        // Set MediaController for VideoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    }

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videolinkurl));
    final Boolean canSeekForward = videoView.canSeekForward();
    System.out.println(canSeekForward);
    final Boolean canSeekBackward = videoView.canSeekBackward();
    System.out.println(canSeekBackward);
    videoView.start();

    // When the video file ready for playback.
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            videoView.seekTo(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                videoView.start();
            }
            else if (canSeekForward && canSeekBackward){
                int currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            else {
                videoView.pause();
            }

        }
    });

    videoView.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            videoView.stopPlayback();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Let the video fully stream and try. If it works properly that's where the error is

Comment: The video streams completely and finishes successfully, however the seek function doesnt work

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939135/6544105